# Changing the image rendering in Konva.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, konvajs

I'm creating a canvas where I have an image of 1000x1000 like r/place. I'd like to show the image zoomed in and being able to see each pixels indecently. It works fine in Konva but it makes [the whole image blurry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZX4Z.jpg).

I would like to know if there were a thing like image-rendering: pixelated like in CSS.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [imageSmoothingEnabled](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Layer.html#imageSmoothingEnabled) property of `Konva.Layer` for that.

```js
const layer = new Konva.Layer({
  imageSmoothingEnabled: false
});
```

https://jsbin.com/roratolewe/edit?html,js,output